# NSInternalInconsistencyException error when inserting row using Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image]

I'm trying to insert a row when my "Save to Diary" button is clicked. However, I keep getting this error:

"'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 3 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'"

Heres my code:

```
 class FoodDiary: UITableViewController, AddRowDelegate {


var tableData = [""]
let foodTimes = ["Add Breakfast","Add Lunch","Add Dinner","Add Snacks"]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.tableData.count
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "diaryEntry" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.first{
        let popVC = segue.destination as! PopupVC
            popVC.delegate = self

            if selectedIndexPath == 0 {
                let label = "Add Breakfast"
                popVC.foodLabel = label
                popVC.section = 0

                }
            if selectedIndexPath == 1{
                let label = "Add Lunch"
                popVC.foodLabel = label
                popVC.section = 1

            }
            if selectedIndexPath == 2 {
                let label = "Add Dinner"
                popVC.foodLabel = label
                popVC.section = 2

            }
            if selectedIndexPath == 3{
                let label = "Add Snacks"
                popVC.foodLabel = label
                popVC.section = 3

            }

        }
    }
  }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FoodDiaryCell

    cell.foodLabel.text = foodTimes[indexPath.section]

return cell
    }

func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String, section: Int) {

    tableData.append(name)
    let rowIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData.count + 1, section: section)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [rowIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Heres my PopUpVC that sends the data to my Food Diary:

```
  protocol AddRowDelegate {
  func didAddRow(name : String, calories : String, section : Int)
 }     


 class PopupVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: AddRowDelegate?
var section: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var foodTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopup2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopUp: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputFood: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputCals: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveToDiary(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    delegate?.didAddRow(name: inputFood.text!, calories: inputCals.text!, section: section!)

}
```

What im basically trying to do is pass the info from PopUpVC to my Food Diary, and inserting the name of the food the user inputed as a row.

Comment: before appending data in your tabledata array you have 1 value means one row.When you called the delegate you appended one more value means 2 rows now.So you have two rows available.You have one section with two rows trying to add one more then you need to append data in array.

Comment: I see, the table data has 1 row because in this specific row I designed it to say "Add Breakfast". How can I add another row before it and let it just say the food name? @TusharSharma

Comment: why dont you just reload table agter appending data.Instead of addRowmethod.

Comment: I'm using the addRow method to grab the data from the PopUpVC and pass it to my FoodDiaryVC using the delegate method. Is this not the proper way to do it? @TusharSharma

Comment: I uploaded a pic to see if it helps clarify what im talking about @TusharSharma

Comment: are you trying to add a new cell on tap and push that add luch below?

Comment: Yes!! @TusharSharma

Comment: you need to understand something here your table maintain data in form of index value .You have 7 rows 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and all are visible.What you are trying to do is add row at index 2 which is already visible there.

Comment: I have 4 sections though, (the blue bar is the header) and for now 1 row at each section. I do want to do what you're saying which is to add a new cell and push the Food times to the bottom.  Thats definitely a good tip though i didnt know that @TusharSharma

Comment: you need to understand how to create expandable table view cells.http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: Ok i think i can work with this... thank you! @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0):

```
let rowIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData.count + 1, section: section)
```

Should be :

```
let rowIndexPath = IndexPath(row: tableData.count - 1, section: section)
```

Comment: I get this error now: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)" I have a default row in my app that tells the user to "Add Breakfast". Let me know if I should upload a pic

Comment: A default row ?

Comment: I uploaded a pic. Basically these rows tells the user to add a specific food during a specific time @GaetanZ

Comment: Try tableData.count rather than tableData.count - 1. But I don't see this default row in your code.

Comment: I basically want to tap "Add Breakfast" and then type in the food that i ate, then save the row, and boom the tableview updates. Does this make sense?